# How can I suppress a range of references with \cite?

Tags: biblatex, citing

I searched already existing questions but could not find, what I was looking for (because it is always the opposite way of what I want to achieve or not the same problem), so I decided to ask this question:

**How can I disable the range of references option of biblatex using the citestyle=numeric-comp temporarily within the document?**

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend = biber,
bibencoding = utf8,
sorting = none,
citestyle = numeric-comp
]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{Quellen/Literaturdatenbank.bib}


\begin{document}

    Citing in the text \textbf{should} use compression/range: \cite{doubleshift-rano,diss-huang,getriebebuch2016,dedizierteHybrid2019} (correct) \\
    
    Within a specific part of the document (in a table) I want to use \textbf{no} range of references and I want to see every number of the used references: \cite{doubleshift-rano,diss-huang,getriebebuch2016,dedizierteHybrid2019} (incorrect) \\
    
    Above it should look like: [1,2,3,4]
    
    \clearpage
    
    \printbibliography[
    heading = bibintoc,
    title = Literaturverzeichnis,
    ]

\end{document}
```

The result looks like this:

[image]

But within the second paragraph I want to **deactivate** the range functionality of "numeric-comp" **temporarily**. Is this somehow possible?

My references.bib is:

```
@article{
    doubleshift-rano,
    author   = {Vanja Ranogajec and Jo\v{s}ko Deur and Vladimir Ivanović and H. Eric Tseng},
    title    = {Multi-objective parameter optimization of control profiles for automatic transmission double-transition shifts},
    journal  = {Control Engineering Practice},
    volume   = {93},
    year     = {2019}
}

@book{
    diss-huang,
    author    = {Hua Huang},
    title     = {Model-based calibration of automated transmissions},
    publisher = {Universitätsverlag der TU Berlin},
    year      = {2016}
}

@book{
    getriebebuch2016,
    author    = {Robert Fischer and Ferit Kü\c{c}ükay and Gunter Jürgens and Burkhard Pollak},
    title     = {Das Getriebebuch - 2., überarbeitete Auflage},
    publisher = {Springer Vieweg},
    year      = {2016}
}

@inbook{dedizierteHybrid2019,
    author    = {Andreas Kinigadner and Christian Lauinger and Laurent Bayoux},
    title     = {Dedizierte Hybridgetriebe},
    booktitle = {Elektrifizierung des Antriebsstrangs - Grundlagen - vom Mikro-Hybrid zum vollelektrischen Antrieb},
    year      = {2019},
    publisher = {Springer Vieweg},
    pages     = {171-182}
}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Kind regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could define yourself another cite command based on the numeric style. I left the space after the comma, there are in numeric-comp too.

Don't use `\\` at the end of paragraphs.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
backend = biber,
bibencoding = utf8,
sorting = none,
citestyle = numeric-comp
]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\newbibmacro*{citeext}{%
  \printtext[bibhyperref]{%
    \printfield{labelprefix}%
    \printfield{labelnumber}%
    \ifbool{bbx:subentry}
      {\printfield{entrysetcount}}
      {}}}


\DeclareCiteCommand{\citeext}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{citeext}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
\begin{document}

    Citing in the text \textbf{should} use compression/range: \cite{doody,herrmann,angenendt,baez/article} (correct),
    \cite{doody,herrmann,baez/article}

    Within a specific part of the document (in a table) I want to use \textbf{no} range of references and I want to see every number of the used references: \citeext{herrmann,angenendt,baez/article,doody} (incorrect) 

    Above it should look like: [1,2,3,4]

  \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: although I should avoid "thanks"-comments, I want to thank you very much and provide the feedback that it worked perfectly and solved my problem!